# Is it possible to use shared memory configuration with ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, dds, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to change the QoS settings to use the shared memory but I got the following error when tying to run a node. It says the  `OpenSpliceDDS` is not running in shared memory mode but I started it by `ospl start` and says `ospl start Domain with name ospl_shmem_ddsi with id 0 is already running, ignoring command`  if I try to start it again. So I am wondering if it is possible to use shared memory configuration with ROS2.

```
========================================================================================
Context     : DDS::DomainParticipantFactory::create_participant
Date        : 2019-05-01T11:08:28+0200
Node        : btopal-ThinkPad-T580
Process     : mock_performance_fast_main <20554>
Thread      : main thread 7fb1726d3f40
Internals   : DomainParticipantFactory.cpp/324/6.9.190403OSS///-1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report      : Unable to connect to domain id = 0.
          The most common causes of this error are an incorrect configuration file or
          that OpenSpliceDDS is not running (when using shared memory mode).
Internals   : u_participantNew/u_participant.c/234/773/1556701708.115704938
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report      : Creation of internal Domain Database failed.
Internals   : user::u_domain::attachToFederatedDomain/u_domain.c/1360/773/1556701708.115716030
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Report      : segment defaultDomainDatabase not found
Internals   : c_base::c_open/c_base.c/1710/0/1556703445.973830343
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:106] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'failed to create domain participant, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rmw-opensplice-cpp-0.6.3/src/rmw_node.cpp:161, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rcl-0.6.5/src/rcl/node.c:402'

with this new error message:

  'rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rcl-0.6.5/src/rcl/node.c:535'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
[ERROR] [rcl]: Failed to fini publisher for node: 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl node: rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-crystal-rcl-0.6.5/src/rcl/node.c:535
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322270/is-it-possible-to-use-shared-memory-configuration-with-ros2/) by [brkk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4761/brkk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2019-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to use opensplice shared memory config within the system, atleast with the dashing release. This feature is only available with the commercial offering of opensplice.

There are some good numbers posted here about a few of the common dds implementations performances:

https://discourse.ros.org/t/is-there-any-dds-implementation-using-shared-memory-inside-system/7609/18

cwyark posts some performance comparisons of opensplice shared memory vs non-shared memory on that thread. There >2x latency improvement with shared memory in hist tests.

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1